# How do signify 'impossibility' in a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on a little sequence. The first few iterations (0 to 2) and all whole number iterations can't be computed because the conditions for the sequence to be calculable aren't met. Only odd iterations including and past the 3rd iteration work. How do I indicate that in the sequence itself? Is there a letter or symbol for that, or do I just skip over the iterations that are not useful?

Something like E, E, E, 8, E, 2456, E, 634680318, E (making up some numbers here, E as in Error)

Or is it just 8, 2456, 634680318?

Comment: Could you not iterate only on numbers that are calculable? Perhaps create a new sequence that contains only the calculable numbers and iterate over those numbers?

Comment: Yeah that's the second example. I'm just wondering if some math etiquette exists when it comes to iterations.

Comment: Perhaps asking a more precise question would help. (e.g. it is not clear at all what "whole numbers" are, especially since you imply that 2 is not "whole"). I think that what you are saying reminds me a bit of the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). Perhaps that could help.

Comment: Wow, you really hit the nail on the head there, I was figuring out something that seemingly had to do with finding derangements of pairs in odd squares. The wiki page on double factorials has a lot of similarity to what I was trying to understand. Thanks a milion, it looks like I have more reading up to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes little sense to consider "impossible" terms of a sequence. Just deal with the sequence

$$8, 2456, 634680318,\cdots
$$

If you want to be more specific, you may state that these are terms are

$$i_3,i_5,i_7,\cdots$$ and leave others undefined.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!